# Filling the missing values by selecting the values in the previous row using R

Tags: r

In my table below, the thrid column is ternary character (A, B & C):  [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xakKA.png)

I like to fill the empty cells with the value from the prevoius cell except for C in this way:[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfmPc.png)

The data frame is:

```
df <- data.frame(
  'ID' = c(1,   2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
  ,'V1' = c("desc1",    "desc2",    "desc3",    "desc4",    "desc5",    "desc6",    "desc7",    "desc8",    "desc9",    "desc10",   "desc11",   "desc12",   "desc13",   "desc14",   "desc15",   "desc16",   "desc17",   "desc18",   "desc19",   "desc20",   "desc21",   "desc22",   "desc23")
  ,'V2' =c("A", "", "", "B",    "", "", "", "C",    "", "A",    "", "", "", "B",    "", "", "C",    "", "A",    "B",    "", "C",    ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(
  'ID' = c(1,   2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
  ,'V1' = c("desc1",    "desc2",    "desc3",    "desc4",    "desc5",    "desc6",    "desc7",    "desc8",    "desc9",    "desc10",   "desc11",   "desc12",   "desc13",   "desc14",   "desc15",   "desc16",   "desc17",   "desc18",   "desc19",   "desc20",   "desc21",   "desc22",   "desc23")
  ,'V2' =c("A", "", "", "B",    "", "", "", "C",    "", "A",    "", "", "", "B",    "", "", "C",    "", "A",    "B",    "", "C",    ""))

df[df == ""] <- NA
setDT(df)[, V2 := zoo::na.locf(V2)] %>% 
  .[, id := rowid(V2), by = rleid(V2)] %>% 
  .[, V2 := ifelse(V2 == "C" & id > 1, NA, V2)] %>% 
  .[, id := NULL] %>% 
  .[]
#>     ID     V1   V2
#>  1:  1  desc1    A
#>  2:  2  desc2    A
#>  3:  3  desc3    A
#>  4:  4  desc4    B
#>  5:  5  desc5    B
#>  6:  6  desc6    B
#>  7:  7  desc7    B
#>  8:  8  desc8    C
#>  9:  9  desc9 <NA>
#> 10: 10 desc10    A
#> 11: 11 desc11    A
#> 12: 12 desc12    A
#> 13: 13 desc13    A
#> 14: 14 desc14    B
#> 15: 15 desc15    B
#> 16: 16 desc16    B
#> 17: 17 desc17    C
#> 18: 18 desc18 <NA>
#> 19: 19 desc19    A
#> 20: 20 desc20    B
#> 21: 21 desc21    B
#> 22: 22 desc22    C
#> 23: 23 desc23 <NA>
#>     ID     V1   V2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok, thank you. But why do I get  "type" and  "res" in the end? Can you please remove them?

Comment: corrected for the data of your example

Comment: Thank you very much Yuriy Saraykin!

Answer (score 0):

We could use `fill` function from `tidyr` package combining with an `ifelse` condition:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%  
  mutate(V3 =  V2) %>% 
  fill(V3) %>% 
  mutate(V3 = ifelse(V3 == "C", V2, V3))
```

Output:

```
      ID V1     V2    V3   
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
 1     1 desc1  A     A    
 2     2 desc2  NA    A    
 3     3 desc3  NA    A    
 4     4 desc4  B     B    
 5     5 desc5  NA    B    
 6     6 desc6  NA    B    
 7     7 desc7  NA    B    
 8     8 desc8  C     C    
 9     9 desc9  NA    NA   
10    10 desc10 A     A    
# … with 13 more rows
```

Comment: Why don't I get the same result as you? For me, V3 is exactly like V2 !!

Comment: There's a step missing, `fill()` needs NA not "" to work.  e.g. after the `mutate(V3 =  V2) %>%`  the next line needs to be `mutate(V3 = ifelse(V3 == "", NA, V3)) %>%`

Comment: Have you loaded all packages? `library(tidyr)`.

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem. You had NA in your Table.

Comment: Thank you very much TarJae. I also use your solution. Thank you!